# Comparing Page Load Time

Tags: page-speed, browsers, tools, page, load-time

How can I save (for a later use in comparison) the page load results totals in chrome`s network panel. The totals are displayed on the status bar but I didnt find a way to save it.

Is there a better method for comparing multiple page load results of a single page?

Comment: If nothing else you could take a screenshot.

Comment: You can also save a `.har` (HTTP Archive) file - this is a JSON file that contains _everything_! (Probably way too much for what you require.) You will need another tool to analyse this file. There are several websites that appear to allow you to compare 2 `.har` files.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Actually Firefox devtools lets me select and copy the statusbar results. I was wandering if there is a more elegant method for comparing multiple results